# How to pass context from TimerTask in android?

Tags: android

Here I am trying this in my project . but it's not working .

[image]

Comment: Nice to put a screenshot but add some context. This is not an image parsing community (I am on small screen cannot see **)

Answer (score 2):

Write this line

```
Final DataBaseHelper dataBaseHelper = new DataBaseHelper(AdminCreateOrLogin.this)
```

instead of

```
Final DataBaseHelper dataBaseHelper = new DataBaseHelper(this)
```

Comment: thank you so much . it's working properly

Comment: If it works for you please accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try: `AdminCreateOrLogin.this` instead of `this`.
The thing is you are inside of an anonymous class method and using `this` inside it will give you the current class (`TimerTask`) in which you operates. If you want to use the class at an upper level you have to prefix it by the name of your class (`AdminCreateOrLogin` in our case).

Answer (score 0):

In your snippet `this` seems to be a reference to the instance of `TimeTask`, since you called it within the inner class. Try to use `AdminCreateOrLogin.this`.